# "Strange" memory leaks - TCP Network

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-leaks, boost-asio

I have a lot of classes building a TCP network - with `boost::asio`, using `Packet`s for transfer. (Base class of `Packet` is `std::vector<char>`)

I thought I had fixed already all possible memory leaks, but then I simply shutdown the server before shutting down the client - which shouldn't cause any problem - and `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` reported memory leaks. So I added the Visual Leaks Detector to the project and checked where these memory leaks occur.

```
void dumpMemoryLeaks(void) { CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
//and in main:
atexit(dumpMemoryLeaks);
```

Checking back to the lines where the memory leak by VLD was reported, it appears to be a little... strange for me.

I have a class `AsyncAcceptor` where I allocate in the constructors initialiser list `new BoostSocket` - raw pointer (Wrapper for normal- and SSL Socket). In the destructor of `AsyncAcceptor` the raw pointer is properly deleted if it is valid.

```
_acceptor = new AsyncAcceptor(service, bindIP, port); //No memory leak for this pointer
//...
_acceptor->AsyncAcceptManaged(_OnSocketAccept); //Function pointer
```

Inside the `AsyncAcceptManaged` the server is waiting for connections and passing another pointer - one memory leak.

```
//Set socket properties
//Call handler function passed as parameter
handler(_socket); //Raw pointer passed to handler
_socket = nullptr;
_socket = new BoostSocket(_acceptor.get_io_service()); //with ctx for SSL, if defined
//If the acceptor is not closed, it calls `AsyncAcceptManaged` again.
```

Now to the handler function.

```
void OnSocketOpen(BoostSocket *sock)
{
    //set additional socket options and check for error
    //Note: SocketType is template parameter of class - allowing different socket types
    std::shared_ptr<SocketType> newSocket(new SocketType(sock));
    delete sock;
    sock = nullptr;
}
```

`SocketType` always has one base class with the same constructor overload for a `BoostSocket *`.

```
Socket(BoostSocket *socket)
    : _socket(std::move(*socket))
{
    //...
}
```

In `BoostSocket` the member _socket is a `std::unique_ptr<SocketType>` where the SocketType is a typedef to either a `tcp::socket` or `boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>`.

```
BoostSocket(BoostSocket &&s)
    : _socket(std::move(s._socket))
{ }
```

---

Visual Leak Detector points to this stack:

1. `AsyncAcceptor::AsyncAcceptManaged`
2. `OnSocketOpen` - the handler
3. The shared_ptr - memory (452) - `explicit shared_ptr(_Ux *_Px)`
4. `void _Resetp(_Ux *_Px)`

There are also smilar "strange" reports.

---

```
Packet p;
//add data & add Packet to a std::queue
QueuePacket(Packet &&p);

//Inside QueuePacket:
_queue.push(std::move(p));
```

Memory leak:

1. queue (111) - `void push(value_type&& _Val)`
2. deque (1181) - `void push_back(value_type&& _Val)`

---

Memory leak (`_socket` is a `std::unique_ptr`):

```
BoostSocket(boost::asio::io_service &ioService)
    : _socket(new SocketType(ioService)) //<--- here
{ }
```

---

Memory leak (`m_Member` is a `std::shared_ptr`):

```
m_Member = std::move(std::shared_ptr<StoredClass>(new StoredClass(shared_from_this()) ) );
```

---

Large memory leak (`_readBuffer` is a `std::vector<char>`):

```
_readBuffer.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(DataUnits::DATA_UNIT_MB) * 5); //resize to 5 MB
```

---

I assume that the last memory leaks are caused due the Socket not being destructed properly as the memory leak reports. Yet I cannot imagine what the problem might be. My raw pointers are handled properly and for anything else I use smart pointers.

> Visual Leak Detector detected 17 memory leaks (5244907 bytes).

**Is this a correct report of VLD ?** I cannot seem to find the memory leak causing everything. Any hints or a solution appreciated.

Comment: Doesnt it give the stack trace like valgrind?

Comment: @Arunmu I've never worked with valgrind, but it does give the stacktrace and I posted the required information out of it in the question. *I can post the full trace **of one or all** if necessary,* though that might be a lot to read.

Comment: Are you running it on linux ? I have never used VLD and there is not enough context in terms of code to make any knowledgeable guess. If you are using linux, run it via `valgrind`.

Comment: @Arunmu This is Visual Studio stuff (i.e., `Windows` platform).

Comment: Ah..should have been an easy guess..If you are comfortable with debugging on linux, then that would be better (atleast for me :)).

Comment: @Arunmu Even if I could debug on Linux, or wanted to, [I can't do anything on Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/789005/oracle-vm-ubuntu-64bit) at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Socket did not get automatically destroyed. I have fixed this issue by closing all left Sockets manually in a loop, after stopping and joining the thread[s], which handle new Sockets/Connections, finished their update loops.

Code looks like this:

```
//_sockets - std::set with std::shared_ptr<SocketType>
if (_stopped) //std::atomic
{
    for (i = _sockets.begin(); i != _sockets.end();)
    {
        if ((*i)->IsOpen() && (*i)->IsSocketOpen())
        {
            (*i)->CloseSocket();
            SocketRemoved(*i); //Do work when client gets disconnected
            --_connections; //std::atomic
        }
        _sockets.erase(i++);
    }
}
```

VLD does not report back any memory leaks, though `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` has it's own opinion.

> No memory leaks detected.
>   Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about whether it could be a false positive or not, you'll want to run the "core logic" of your program in a loop in a debugger. At megabytes at a time, that should confirm pretty quickly whether memory is getting leaked or not.

As to the actual design of your program:

> My raw pointers are handled properly and for anything else I use smart pointers.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> void OnSocketOpen(BoostSocket *sock)
> {
>     //set additional socket options and check for error
>     //Note: SocketType is template parameter of class - allowing different socket types
>     std::shared_ptr<SocketType> newSocket(new SocketType(sock));
>     delete sock;
>     sock = nullptr;
> }
> ```

That statement, and the code I'm sampling, seem to be at odds with each other.

In general, with C++11/C++14, the usual advice is to never, **ever** deal with raw pointers, and to never, **ever** deal with explicit `new` or `delete` keywords. Obviously, no rule is ever 100% infallible (and I advise you write that in sharpie on your computer monitor), but in this case, I'd say it's still true 99.99...% of the time.

So every time you're dealing with raw pointers, you'll either want to replace them with `std::unique_ptr` (if it owns the object) or `std::shared_ptr` (if multiple objects own it), if you haven't already done so already. I see that you're already using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for some of your objects; make sure that you're doing this for *all* of your pointers.

Secondly, replace every use of `new` with the appropriate `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared`. Eliminate any and all references to `delete` unless you're writing a customer deleter; and even then, be sure that's actually what you need.

Thirdly, be very careful about the semantics of your code:

```
m_Member = std::move(std::shared_ptr<StoredClass>(new StoredClass(shared_from_this()) ) );
```

There is, as a general rule of thumb, no reason to ever "move" a `std::shared_ptr`. The reason `std::shared_ptr` exists is to allow for safe copy semantics of pointers, and in the scenarios where moves are the appropriate choice, the Compiler is usually smart enough to figure it out for you. This code itself is probably fine (though the std::move is redundant) but there may be other code areas you'll want to look at.

I can't point to any specific code that might be the culprit (especially since we don't have the full code listing here) but if you fix all those problems, it'll very likely fix the memory leak(s).

Comment: I've replaced now every location using a `std::make_shared` / `std::make_unique` where I use code like above. Apparently that fixed 2 leaks, thank you. Replacing all left raw pointers with smart pointers fixed 0 memory leaks. I can update my question with the stack trace of VLD pointing to the memory leak that most likely causes the other leaks. - If you're able to help with that / give a few hints that might cause it. I'll update this if I'm able to find it myself. IMO the socket does not get destroyed when the server is shutdown before the client.